# Why does substitution only work in italic in LuaLaTeX?

Tags: luatex, fontspec

I am trying out this simple substitution in LuaLaTeX, after confirming for this font (using FontForge) that the right alternate glyph is `Q.d` in both the roman and italic.  Yet, this MWE produces the desired substitution only in the italic....

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont[RawFeature={+qalt}]{Arno Pro}
\directlua{%
fonts.handlers.otf.addfeature{
    name = "qalt",
    type = "chainsubstitution",
    lookups = {
      {
        type = "substitution",
        data = {
          ["Q"] = "Q.d",
        },
      },
    },
    data = {
      rules = {
        {
          after  = { { "u" } },
          current = { { "Q" } },
          lookups = { 1 },
        },
      },
    },
  }
}


\begin{document}
 Queen  \itshape Queen\end{document}
```

[image]

For clarification, here is the desired effect manually turned on in my text-editor:

[image]

Comment: Are you sure it's not being substituted on the left? That Q looks pretty swashy to me. What should `Q.d` look like for Arno Pro?

Comment: @Davislor Yes, there's a ridiculously swashy Q swash I'm going for —I'll add a screenshot to make it clear

Comment: Please try putting `\setmainfont` after the `\directlua` block.

Comment: @HenriMenke Brilliant—fixed it.  It also messed up another part of my actual working document (which is an unwieldy mess), but that's another question for another time.  If you make that an answer, I'll accept and upvote.